# Spring Boot not recognize controller with send request parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The spring boot do not recognize my controllers only if i send more parameters on request. For example:

If i send normal **GET** request the spring boot **recognize** my controller:
`http://localhost/idp/oauth/123/authorize`

If i send **GET** request with **extras parameters** the spring boot **do not recognize** my controller:
`http://localhost/idp/oauth/123/authorize?scope=public_profile`

I need receive the request exactly for second example (with parameter scope), but the spring boot do not recognize the controller and redirect to /error.

code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/idp/oauth")
public class OAuthController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{clientId}/authorize", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String authorizeGet(
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, 
            @PathVariable String clientId,
            Model model) {
            // ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{clientId}/authorize", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String authorizePost(
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, 
            @PathVariable String clientId,
            Model model) {
            // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding [`@RequestParam`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param)s?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are passing extra param with name "scope" Spring will search for `@RequestParam` in methods 
It can't find any, thus the error

You need to modify your method to add all `@RequestParam`

You can also add optional fields if they are not mandatory with `required = false`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{clientId}/authorize", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String authorizeGet(
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, 
        @PathVariable String clientId,
        @RequestParam(value = "scope") String scope,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "optionalParam") String optionalParam,
        Model model) {
        // ...
}
```

Comment: Adding the '@RequestParam(name = "scope") String scope' dont work :(. the redirect /error continue.

Comment: Can you add Serevr log what errror exactly you are getting.

Comment: Instead of name try "value = "scope"  . I have edited

Comment: I try using "value = scope" but dont works :(
The spring redirect me to /error. (the recognize url, but if i send parameters do not recognize more)...

Answer (score 1):

You missed `@RequestParam` in the controller method definition.

[More](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param) on `@RequestParam`